# SceneKit SCNMatrix4Mult EXC_BAD_ACCESS on M1

Tags: segmentation-fault, scenekit, apple-m1, rosetta-2

Using Xcode Version 13.0 (13A233) MacOS BigSur 11.6, I made a new command line app, and in it's main type:

```
import SceneKit
let _ = SCNMatrix4Mult(SCNMatrix4Identity, SCNMatrix4Identity)
```

When run on a 2013 intel machine, works and exits without error.
When run on Apple M1, it reports

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20)

This forces me to run in Rosetta mode, and significant speed impact.

Can others reproduce this? It's pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed on Monterey 12.0.1 (21A559) Xcode 13.1 (13A1030d)